# Django/Python: import error in celery taks.py

Tags: python, django, django-celery, celery-task, celeryd

I am facing an import error inside celery task.py. The class StockManager method which is in another package is used to save the details. However i am getting and import error for StockManager(). How can i resolve this issue. Am i doing anything wrong?

```
Folder structure
src
    -tradeapp
    -logic              --> Common businesss logic layer
    -asynctaskmanager   --> Here the task.py and celery resides

from djcelery import celery
from logic.StockManager import StockManager


@celery.task
def save_stock_data(details):
    stock_mngr = StockManager()
    is_saved   = stock_mngr.save_data(details)
    return is_saved
```

Thanks

Comment: How you are running celery? using supervisor or anything else?

Comment: Is all OK if you try to import this module in python shell?

Comment: We need more information about your project structure and where is the logic folder

Comment: Folder structure has been updated above, and i am running celeryd in the console.

Comment: Are you using manage.py or straight up celeryd? ie: python manage.py celery or celeryd

Comment: i am using manage.py celeryd -l

Comment: Resolved the issue using modules instead of class for now.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the celery documentation docs. Specifically on how to structure a project using celery. [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).